# how to make <dbl [1]> appear like a number in chunk markdown in R

Tags: r

When I use my code and run all without Markdow, I can see p-value numbers, but when I use the chunk R, the value becomes like this
Here is my code

```
# Now test for normality
data%>%
  select_if(is.numeric)%>%
  sapply(shapiro.test)%>%
  t()%>%
  data.frame()%>%
  dplyr::select(p.value)%>%
  mutate(Is_normally_distributed=p.value>=0.05)
```

the result in Markdow
[image]

Here when there is no chunck

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue, so this is just a guess, but perhaps if you add `%>% 
print.data.frame()` to the end of your command it will solve the issue?

Comment: The issue is your the code `sapply(shapiro.test)` returns a matrix of list elements which you then convert to a data frame.  This prints nicely using the default print method, however, the chunk preview mode automatically converts data frames to tibbles which shows that your data frame columns are actually list elements.  You can avoid this by using `data %>% select(where((is.numeric))) %>% map_dfr(~ shapiro.test(.x) %>% `[`("p.value"), .id = "var") %>% mutate(Is_normally_distributed=p.value>=0.05)`.

Comment: I can reproduce this in R Markdown, and as jared mamrot suggested, print.data.frame works well with it.

Comment: Thanks@RitchieSacramento. I tried ues what you suggested then I got this error Error in shapiro.test(.x) %>% ("p.value") : attempt to apply non-function. I still want the chunk to be previewed as mode automatically. Because my goal is to convert this to HTML page so I believe I need to tune this a bit.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape the backticks in the above comment:  it should be `shapiro.test(.x) %>% \`[\`("p.value")`.